# Trouble injecting the build block while exporting a Maven pom.xml file from gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-plugin, pom.xml

```
task writeNewPom {
    pom {
        project {
            /*
            build {
                plugins {
                    plugin {
                        groupId 'GROUP_ID'
                        artifactId 'maven-ipcentral-plugin'
                        version '4.7'
                        executions {}
                        configuration {
                            url "http://CENTRAL_REPORTING_SERVER"
                            logfileprefix "test"
                            ipcProject = true
                            businessUnit "FOUR_DIGIT_CODE"
                            componentEditorsGrouper "ccp-dev"
                            assetEditorsGrouper "ccp-dev"
                            username "USERNAME"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            */
            pluginRepositories {
                pluginRepository {
                    id 'ipcentral-snapshots'
                    name 'IPCentral Snapshot Repository'
                    url 'http://PLUGIN_SOURCE/'
                    snapshots {
                        enabled = false
                    }
                    releases {
                        enabled = true
                    }
                }
            }

            profiles {
                profile {
                    id 'inject-cec-credentials'
                    activation {
                        activeByDefault = true
                    }
                    properties {
                        username = "USERNAME"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("ipcentral/pom.xml")
}
```

I am attempting to create a pom.xml file using the gradle maven plugin.  It must reference a maven plugin designed for central dependency reporting.  As it is right now it successfully creates the pom.xml file containing all dependencies, plugin repository info, and profile info.  However if the build section is un-commented the I get an error along the lines of:

```
> No such property: _SCRIPT_CLASS_NAME_ for class: org.apache.maven.model.
```

If I try something simple like

```
task writeNewPom {
    pom {
        project {
            build {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then I get the same error.  It seems that gradle does not recognize build as a valid identifier.  I am just hoping for a more elegant solution than manually editing xml through groovy.  The only documentation on this that I can find is [Gradle docs Chap 53](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the `project {...}` closure is delegating to an instance of `ModelBuilder` which extends Groovy's `FactoryBuilderSupport` class that already defines a method named `build`. So instead of configuring the `build` property of the Maven `Model` object, the preexisting `build` method is being called.

To get around this I'd use `withXml {...}` to configure that portion of your pom.

```
pom {
    project {
        // other non-<build> configuration
    }
}.withXml {
    asNode().appendNode('build').appendNode('plugins').appendNode('plugin').with {
        appendNode('groupId', 'GROUP_ID')
    }
}.writeTo('pom.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more detailed example:

```
.withXml
{
    asNode().appendNode('build').appendNode('plugins').with
                                                       {

                                                           with
                                                           {


                                                                appendNode('plugin')
                                                                .with
                                                                {

                                                                appendNode('groupId', 'groupId1')

                                                                appendNode('artifactId', 'artifactId1')

                                                                appendNode('version', 'version1')
                                                                }


                                                           }
                                                       with
                                                           {
                                                                appendNode('plugin')
                                                                .with{
                                                                appendNode('groupId', 'groupId2')

                                                                appendNode('artifactId', 'artifactId2')

                                                                appendNode('version', 'version2')
                                                                }

                                                           }
                                                       }
}
.writeTo("pom.xml")
```